# How to install kubectl in kubernetes container through docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I want to run 'kubectl' commands in the container, so i want to install kubectl in the container while building the Docker image.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a Dockerfile?  An existing pattern for accessing the Kubernetes API from pods that you're working from?

Answer (score 35):

put this in your Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 24):

`kubectl` is written in go, so is completely self-contained.

You can therefore copy it from another container that already includes it. Like I do here, copying it from `bitnami/kubectl:1.20.9`:

```
FROM bitnami/kubectl:1.20.9 as kubectl

FROM ubuntu-or-whatever-image:tag

# Do whatever you need to with the
# ubuntu-or-whatever-image:tag image, then:

COPY --from=kubectl /opt/bitnami/kubectl/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/
```

I like this better than fiddling with `curl`, because now you're taking advantage of Dockers ability to cache the `bitnami/kubectl:1.20.9` image.

Comment: so much better than the other answers - thanks Peter

Comment: I like this solution, but how would I know for certain that the binary will work with different architectures and platform? For example, if my base image may be alpine linux or ubuntu, will this solution still work? What happens if the CPU architecture also differs?

Comment: it's also great for multi-arch dockerfiles - no need to worry about downloading the correct binary

Answer (score 8):

You just need to map `kubectl` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/kubectl`) binary file and `kubeconfig` (e.g. `/root/.kube/config`) into your container.

For example (yaml file for Deployment):

```
      containers:
      - image: container-image-name
        name: container-name
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubectl-binary
          mountPath: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
          readOnly: true
        - name: kubectl-config
          mountPath: /root/.kube/config
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: kubectl-binary
        hostPath:
          path: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
      - name: kubectl-config
        hostPath:
          path: /root/.kube/config
```

P.S.

use the following command to download `kubectl` binary file on each node, and copy `/root/.kube/config` to each node:

```
$ curl -L https://dl.k8s.io/v1.10.6/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case paths are little different but its working fine. 
For kubectl - `/usr/bin/kubectl`
For config - `/etc/kubernetes/config`

Answer (score 3):

Weike's solution works fine for me with different kubectl path, any how if some one looking for solution to install the kubectl in the Docker image then here is the Docker file (it also installs python and kubernetes python client api, if we want to access cluster through python client api):

```
FROM base_image

WORKDIR /tmp


RUN  /usr/bin/curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl \
     && chmod +x ./kubectl  \
     &&  mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
     && zypper install -y python2 \
     && zypper install -y python2-pip \
     && pip install kubernetes \
     && zypper install -y git \
     && zypper clean -a \
     && git clone --recursive https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python.git \
     && cd python \
     && python setup.py install
```

Also here is my deployment file to map kubectl binary and configuration to container to access kubectl in the kubernetes container with in the pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: support
  labels:
    app: support
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: support
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: support
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: mysecret
      containers:
        - name: support
          image: image-name
          command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - "sleep infinity"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: kubectl-binary
            mountPath: /usr/bin/kubectl
            readOnly: true
          - name: kubectl-config
            mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/config
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: kubectl-binary
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/bin/kubectl
        - name: kubectl-config
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/kubernetes/config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have docker you can do whatever you want really since you can pull and start any image. So if you want to build and deploy:

```
docker login
docker build foo/bar .
docker push
docker run -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl set image deploy bar app=foo/bar
```