# Is it possible to pass Kubernetes Cronjob status.lastScheduleTime timestamp to the container of scheduled job?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a cronjob that should process events occurred since the last operation, for that I use DB to persist this timestamp, my question is whether or not it is possible to directly pass Kubernetes **status.lastScheduleTime** into the cronjob object as an environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the easiest way accomplish your goal via `kubectl set env` command, injecting into the particular [Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) template object the desired `status.lastScheduleTime` field as [environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) variable `LAST_SCHEDULE`:

`kubectl set env cronjob/name LAST_SCHEDULE=$(kubectl get cronjob name -o jsonpath='{.status.lastScheduleTime}')`

```
env:
- name: LAST_SCHEDULE
  value: "2019-09-23T08:56:00Z"
```

You may also find a more comprehensive way achieving `Cronjob` resource patching, supplying target environment variable  in the corresponded template with most recent `lastScheduleTime` value via *[Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)* or through `postStart`/`preStop` *[handlers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers)*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but for the solution to work (whether the command to retrieve lastScheduleTime and set LAST_SCHEDULE is provided in postStart or in an init container) I need to know is it possible to run kubectl commands to patch a resource from within the container/pod? ... I mean without having to curl k8s API and authenticate to access just the same cluster the container is in, Thanks

Comment: Indeed you can install `kubectl` command line tool inside the container and supply it with corresponded `kubeconfig` file which will point to the target k8s cluster, as for example look at this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717471/how-to-install-kubectl-in-kubernetes-container-through-docker-image/51795179#51795179).