# Is it possible to grep pod logs for the readiness test?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know this can be worked around by using `exec` and looking at a file inside the pod, e.g.

```yaml
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
```

But want to know if there's any way to grep the logs collected by the kubelet (i.e. that you see with `kubectl logs` and fail readiness based on, for example, grepping for `error`?

Answer (score 0):

In a Kubernetes environment, you can filter specific logs in pod using the following command:

[image]

This command retrieves the logs from the specified pod, searches for lines containing the word "error", and saves those lines to a file named app.log. This is a common way to filter logs and capture only the relevant information for debugging or analysis purposes.

If you intend to search logs within a container, it's necessary to construct an image and incorporate the kubectl command. For guidance on installing kubectl within a Kubernetes container via a Docker image, you can find the necessary information in the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717471/how-to-install-kubectl-in-kubernetes-container-through-docker-image).

"After referring to the article, you can proceed to modify your YAML file by including the kubectl logs command."

[image]